# Neo4j APOC assignedRelationshipProperties, removedRelationshipProperties triggers and apoc.index.in

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I use `Neo4j 3.3.5 Community Edition` with `APOC apoc-3.3.0.2-all.jar`

I have triggers that allow me to add/remove all properties from a particular relationships to/from manual index:

```
CALL apoc.trigger.add('HAS_VALUE_ON_CREATED_RELATIONSHIPS_TRIGGER',
'UNWIND {createdRelationships} AS r 
MATCH (d:Decision)-[r:HAS_VALUE_ON]->(ch:Characteristic) 
CALL apoc.index.addRelationship(r, keys(r)) RETURN count(*)', {phase:'after'})

CALL apoc.trigger.add('HAS_VALUE_ON_DELETED_RELATIONSHIPS_TRIGGER',
\"UNWIND {deletedRelationships} AS r 
MATCH (d:Decision)-[r:HAS_VALUE_ON]->(Characteristic) 
CALL apoc.index.removeRelationshipByName('HAS_VALUE_ON', r) RETURN count(*)\", {phase:'after'})
```

My business logic can also introduce new properties or remove existing ones from the existing relationship so I think in order to keep my index up to date I should also use another two statements, like:

```
assignedRelationshipProperties
removedRelationshipProperties
```

am I right? If so, could you please show how both of them can be used in order to add new triggers and update/remove properties in index from `MATCH (d:Decision)-[r:HAS_VALUE_ON]->(ch:Characteristic)` relationship ?

**UPDATE #1**

I have verified solution provided in the answer section  but unfortunately it doesn't work. Please see details below:

I have created the following trigger:

```
CALL apoc.trigger.add('TEST_TRIGGER', "UNWIND keys({assignedRelationshipProperties}) AS key 
UNWIND {assignedRelationshipProperties}[key] AS map 
WITH map 
WHERE type(map.relationship) = 'LIVES_IN' 
CALL apoc.index.addRelationship(map.relationship, keys(map.relationship)) 
RETURN count(*)", {phase:'before'})
```

verified that trigger exists by `CALL apoc.trigger.list()`

create the following nodes and relationship:

```
CREATE (p:Person) return p
CREATE (c:City) return c

MATCH (p:Person), (c:City) CREATE (p)-[r:LIVES_IN]->(c) RETURN type(r)
```

tried to access it by index query:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[r:LIVES_IN]->(c:City) 
CALL apoc.index.in(c, 'LIVES_IN', 'time:10') YIELD node AS person 
RETURN person
```

the quthe ery returns empty result which is fine for now.

assigned relationship new property `time` with value = `10`:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[r:LIVES_IN]->(c:City) SET r.time = 10 RETURN r
```

tried to access it by index query:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[r:LIVES_IN]->(c:City) 
CALL apoc.index.in(c, 'LIVES_IN', 'time:10') YIELD node AS person 
RETURN person
```

the query successfully returns the expected `Person` node

Now, I reassigned the `time` property another value = `11`

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[r:LIVES_IN]->(c:City) SET r.time = 11 RETURN r
```

tried to access it by index query one more time:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[r:LIVES_IN]->(c:City)
CALL apoc.index.in(c, 'LIVES_IN', 'time:10') YIELD node AS person 
RETURN person

MATCH (p:Person)-[r:LIVES_IN]->(c:City) 
CALL apoc.index.in(c, 'LIVES_IN', 'time:11') YIELD node AS person 
RETURN person
```

the query returns empty result for both of them..

Why was the index not updated after the property change?

**UPDATE #2**

I have created the following trigger:

```
CALL apoc.trigger.add('HAS_VALUE_ON_ASSIGNED_RELATIONSHIP_PROPERTIES_TRIGGER',
"UNWIND apoc.trigger.propertiesByKey({assignedRelationshipProperties}, 'time') AS prop WITH prop.relationship as r 
CALL apoc.index.addRelationship(r, keys(r)) 
RETURN count(*)", {phase:'after'})
```

verified that trigger exists by `CALL apoc.trigger.list()`

create the following nodes and relationship:

```
CREATE (p:Person) return p
CREATE (c:City) return c

MATCH (p:Person), (c:City) CREATE (p)-[r:LIVES_IN]->(c) RETURN type(r)
```

tried to access it by index query:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[r:LIVES_IN]->(c:City)
CALL apoc.index.in(c, 'LIVES_IN', 'time:10') YIELD node AS person 
RETURN person
```

the query returns empty result which is fine for now.

assigned relationship new property `time` with value = `10`:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[r:LIVES_IN]->(c:City) SET r.time = 10 RETURN r
```

tried to access it by index query:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[r:LIVES_IN]->(c:City) 
CALL apoc.index.in(c, 'LIVES_IN', 'time:10') YIELD node AS person 
RETURN person
```

the query successfully returns the expected `Person` node

Now, I reassigned the `time` property another value = `11`

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[r:LIVES_IN]->(c:City) SET r.time = 11 RETURN r
```

tried to access it by index query one more time:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[r:LIVES_IN]->(c:City) 
CALL apoc.index.in(c, 'LIVES_IN', 'time:10') YIELD node AS person 
RETURN person

MATCH (p:Person)-[r:LIVES_IN]->(c:City) 
CALL apoc.index.in(c, 'LIVES_IN', 'time:11') YIELD node AS person 
RETURN person
```

the query returns empty result for both of them..

So, this approach ran into the same issue as I previously described above. And the other drawback is that I need to specify the exact key name - in this case `time`. But I'm not interested in some certain key but instead I'm interested in the add/update/delete of all keys of the `HAS_VALUE_ON` relationship.

Comment: it seems to related to the update and the `index.in` query, not to triggers. as regular relationship index works.

Comment: @MichaelHunger Thanks! Is there a chance to get it working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `assignedRelationshipProperties` is quite tricky. The structure of this parameter is `Map<String, List<Map<String, Object>>>`.

Where, the first `String` is the key of the property, and the list elements are maps with the following keys :

- key : the key of the property
- old: the old value if any
- new : the new value assigned to the property
- relationship: the relationship in question

To be more visual, this is what the parameter look like in a debug format :

[image]

For your particular use case, updating the lucene index on relationship property updates for a particular relationship type, you can use the following query :

```
CALL apoc.trigger.add('test-rel-trigger', 
'UNWIND keys({assignedRelationshipProperties}) AS key
UNWIND {assignedRelationshipProperties}[key] AS map
WITH map WHERE type(map.relationship) = "HAS_VALUE_ON"
CALL apoc.index.addRelationship(map.relationship, keys(map.relationship)) RETURN count(*)'
, {phase:'before'})
```

As for removal, because you index the full map of properties, I believe you can just replace `assignedRelationshipProperties` with `removedRelationshipProperties`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I verified this solution but unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: @MichaelHunger sorry, I forgot to mention that I have provided the detailed explanation of this(what doesn't work with this approach) in my updated question - the section UPDATE #1

Comment: Looks like this issue was fixed in Neo4j 3.4.0/apoc-3.4.0.1-all.jar

Answer (score 1):

There are dedicated helper functions for using these, which are explained in the docs to access nodes/rels or properties of those data structures:

see: https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_triggers

#### Table 4. Helper Functions

```
apoc.trigger.nodesByLabel({assignedLabels/assignedNodeProperties},'Label')
```

function to filter labelEntries by label, to be used within a trigger statement with `{assignedLabels}` and `{removedLabels}` 
`{phase:'before/after/rollback'}` 
returns previous and new trigger information

```
apoc.trigger.propertiesByKey({assignedNodeProperties},'key')
```

function to filter propertyEntries by property-key, to be used within a trigger statement with `{assignedNode/RelationshipProperties}` and `{removedNode/RelationshipProperties}`.

Returns `[{old,[new],key,node,relationship}]`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please see my updated question(UPDATE #2). With this approach I also ran into the same issue as I previously described above. And the other drawback is that I need to specify the exact key name - in this case `time`. But I'm not interested in some certain key but instead I'm interested in the add/update/delete of all keys of the `HAS_VALUE_ON` relationship. What am I doing wrong and how to fix it ?

Comment: btw. I think it would be nice to also allow the function to filter for labels/rel-types perhaps you want to create an GH issue for apoc on that

Comment: Thanks, I have created GH issue already https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/issues/805

Comment: One more GH issue for Neo4j: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/11789